# What is the difference between Heap memory and string constant pool in java

Tags: java, string

In Java

1. Object created using **new operator** will be stored in the **heap
   memory**.
2. The object created using **string literal** is stored in
   the **string constant pool**

I'm running the below code to check the hashcode.

```
    String nameOne = "Deepak";
    String nameTwo = new String("Deepak");
    System.out.println("nameOne address    -- "+nameOne.hashCode());
    System.out.println("nameTwo address    -- "+nameTwo.hashCode());
```

output of the code is

```
nameOne address    -- 2043177526
nameTwo address    -- 2043177526
```

Both objects are created using new operator and string literal and stored in different places heap memory and string constant pool accordingly. Then how the memory address is same.

Please explain about the concept, if i'm wrong

Comment: The hash code of a `String` is nothing to do with the memory address. The hash code is based on the *value* of the string. Two strings with the same value *must* have the same hash code.

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool this might HELP

Comment: @khelwood : thanks bro, know i understood

Comment: thanks @RahulSingh

Answer (score 3):

It is not correct to compare heap and constant pool. Especially using `hashCode`.

Let's go step by step:

1. Since Java 7 string pool is inside the heap memory. [Read more](http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/).
2. **HashCode in Java is not related to memory address***

   JVM has an arg to specify hashCode default algorithm

   `-XX:hashCode=k`

   Number `k` could be one of:

   1. Park-Miller [RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator)
   2. foo(address, global state)
   3. 1 (const)
   4. incremental (++)
   5. address
   6. thread-local [Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) (default in HotSpot, java 8)
3. String override default `hashCode` implementation. It is based on string content. 
   `java.lang.String`:

   ```
   public int hashCode() {
       int h = hash;
       if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
           char val[] = value;
           for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
               h = 31 * h + val[i];
           }
           hash = h;
       }
       return h;
   }
   ```